# How can i get a value from a JSON object with no key

Tags: javascript, json, response, key-value

I am making a http request and then I get values from a SQL table.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    controller.getAllPosts( function(err,posts){
        if(err){
            res.status(500);
            res.end();
        }else{           
            res.json(posts);
}
```

The response I get is like this:

```
[
  {
    "id_post": 1,
    "description": "Hola",
    "username": "jumavipe",
    "image": "1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id_post": 2,
    "description": "no se",
    "username": "jacksonjao",
    "image": "2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id_post": 3,
    "description": "nuevo tatuaje de bla bla bla",
    "username": "jumavipe",
    "image": "3.jpg"
  }
]
```

How do I get only the description from post 3

I can't do:

```
var desc= posts[2].description
```

I looked online and I tried something like this:

```
var description = posts.getJSONObject("LabelData").getString("description");
```

What should I use as a parameter in the `getJSONObject()` if my json array doesn't have a key.

I can't find something that works. How can I get that value from one object from the json array?

Comment: indexing starts from 0, so you need `posts[2].description` instead.

Comment: And note that this has nothing to do with JSON. By the time you're trying to access that value, you're accessing an array of objects, not a *string*. JSON is a textual notation. You only deal with *JSON* in JavaScript if you're dealing with a *string*.

Comment: *"i looked online and i tried something like this"* Those were apparently Java resources. Java != JavaScript.

Comment: Do you mean to say "How do I get only the description from the post where `id_post` is 3?

Comment: Related: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using `Array.prototype.find`

If you don't have any browser compatibility issues, you can use `Array.prototype.find`

```
var posts = [
  {
    "id_post": 1,
    "description": "Hola",
    "username": "jumavipe",
    "image": "1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id_post": 2,
    "description": "no se",
    "username": "jacksonjao",
    "image": "2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id_post": 3,
    "description": "nuevo tatuaje de bla bla bla",
    "username": "jumavipe",
    "image": "3.jpg"
  }
];

var post = posts.find(function(item) {
  return item.id_post == 3;
});

console.log(post.description);
```

## Using `Array.prototype.filter`

`Array.prototype.filter` is supported in almost most of the browsers and it will work.

```
var selected_posts = posts.filter(function(item) {
  return item.id_post == 3;
});

console.log(selected_posts[0].description);
```

Comment: Thanks @JulianaVillegas and if it worked, mark it as selected. :)